# Is it possible to set up the rpy2 with system R

Tags: python, r, anaconda, rstudio, rpy2

Briefly speaking, I want to install **rpy2** to connect python seamlessly with R. I have already installed the python 3 in anaconda and installed the system R with Rstudio and both of them work properly in general. Now I want to setup the **rpy2** to connect them together, however, when I type `conda install rpy2` in terminal (I'm a Mac OSX user), it will install the **r-base** within the anaconda which is not what I intend to do. I wonder whether it's feasible that it wouldn't install this **r-base**, but integrates the **anaconda python** with the **system R** instead as I've already had all the needed packages installed in this version of R(studio).

Comment: What is *system R*? Please point to links if it is distinct from the R language.

Comment: @Parfait  the anaconda one means the one in "/Users/names/anaconda3/bin/R" and sytem R means the one in "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/R"

Answer (score 0):

If the R installation you wish to use is the first one found through the environment variable `PATH`, just use `python -m pip install rpy2` to install.

Comment: I add the command `export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources:$PATH"` in the .bash_profile which makes *-bash /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources* return as the first using `$PATH`. However, `python -m pip install rpy2` doesn't work, therefore, I tried `python -m conda install rpy2` instead, but it seems that it will still install the R packages into anaconda.